# Is there a way to replicate certain part of collection in Mongodb

Tags: replication, mongodb, schema, tokumx

Is there away to stream certain part of collection in `MongoDB` or `TokuMX` from master server to another server? I need to duplicate only certain collection

Or if it isn't possible, are there any other alternative for database that doesn't enforce schema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MongoDB at least to current version 2.6+ for sure does not support that as build-in functionality. I guess because a replica set using selective replication won't be consistent.

There is a feature called filtered replication in Couch but never tried it:
http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Replication#Filtered_Replication

Answer (score 1):

The filtered replication is not something that is currently implemented in MongoDB out of the box.

That said, the replication in MongoDB is based on a special collection named "[oplog](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/replica-set-oplog/)", that you can listen to and do the filter yourself, and in this case implement the filter you want to push data into another cluster. (This will be viewed as 2 different clusters, not a single ReplicaSet)

As a starting point I am inviting you to look a the MongoDB Connector, that allow you to capture the changes in the oplog:

https://github.com/10gen-labs/mongo-connector